Recreating a blade in CAD using a data file from Matlab
I'm running a numerical data model of a wind turbine. I know the blade in question is an S814, as described in the NREL documentation here. I have the necessary blade size data in a MATLAB file shown below:

So far, I know that Cd and Cl are the drag and lift data, thetad is the angle and cdist is the chord distribution. But then I have the these questions to make sense of the data:

What is the section area? Is it the total area of the blade between two lines when I cut it into pieces? And why is it constant? Should it not be, or is it?
The variables cdr and rd are two variables whose meanings I do not understand. I only know that both have the same values as shown below, which suggests that they are geometric properties of the blade at a certain section, I suppose?


The only other clue I have is that Cdr an rd are multiplied by the radius of the section as shown in the code below:

I will keep diving to know how to do it but any idea or advice will be really helpful.
